# Fix width of element in UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I create `UIStackView`s programmatically and add them to parent `UIStackView`, which is created in Storyboard. Child stack views are horizontal with 2 labels. I need to fix width of second `UILabel` and make the first `UILabel` fill the rest space.

Now I have this:

[image: Before]

And I want this:

[image: After]

My code for generating children stack views:

```
@IBOutlet weak var parentStackView: UIStackView!

func addStackViewsToParentStackView(params: [String: Float]) {
    for (name, value) in params {
        let parameterNameLabel = UILabel() // first label
        parameterNameLabel.text = name
        let parameterValueLabel = UILabel() // second label
        parameterValueLabel.text = value.description
        parameterValueLabel.frame.size.width = 80.0 // I've tried to fix width, but it does't help

        let childStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [parameterNameLabel, parameterValueLabel])
        childStackView.axis = .Horizontal
        childStackView.distribution = .FillProportionally
        childStackView.alignment = .Fill
        childStackView.spacing = 5
        childStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        parentStackView.addArrangedSubview(childStackView)
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Just put width constraints on the labels.

```
parameterValueLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
```